get the types from the array of object as key of object with Predefined Type
Code
const fields:magicField[] = [
  {
    type: "select",
    RenderComponent: CustomInput,
    config: {
      label: "First Name",
      placeholder: "First Name",
      name: "firstName" ,
      validation: z.string().min(1),
      options: () => [
        { label: "First Name", value: "First Name" },
        { label: "Second Name", value: "Second Name" },
      ],
    },
  },
];

I want to convert this fields.config.name as the key of object
ConvertedObj.firstName (TypeSafe)
...and so on
Defined Types
export type ValidationType = ZodString | ZodNumber | ZodEnum | ZodNativeEnum;
export type commonConfig = {
  label: string;
  placeholder: string;
  className?: string;
  readonly name: string;
  disabled?:boolean
  validation: ValidationType;
}
export type magicFieldSelect = {
  type: "select";
  config: commonConfig & magicFieldSelectConfig;
}
export type magicFieldInput = {
  type: "input";
  config: commonConfig & magicFieldInputConfig;
}
export type magicFieldSelectConfig = {
  options: () => Promise<optionType[]> | optionType[];
};
export type magicFieldInputConfig = {
  type: HTMLInputTypeAttribute;
};
export type magicField = Readonly<(magicFieldSelect | magicFieldInput) & {RenderComponent: RenderComponent}>
export type typeWithRenderField<T> = T & {
  control: Control<z.infer<formSchema>>;
};
export type InputFieldWithRenderFields = Partial<typeWithRenderField<magicFieldInput["config"]>>;
export type SelectFieldWithRenderFields = Partial<typeWithRenderField<magicFieldSelect["config"]>>;
export type inputFieldWithRenderFieldFn = React.FunctionComponent<InputFieldWithRenderFields>
export type selectFieldWithRenderFieldFn = React.FunctionComponent<SelectFieldWithRenderFields>
export type RenderComponent = inputFieldWithRenderFieldFn |  selectFieldWithRenderFieldFn;

I Googled it and found
I can use this types
type ResultType = {
  [K in ArrayItem['name']]: ArrayItem['value'];
};

This did't gave me the typesafety
as i was Researching i found it only work in readonly (as const) types
so i tried everything like

adding the readonly to every property
adding the as const to every property

the one that worked was

adding the as const to fields.config.name
and removing the type magicFields[] from the fields variable

But I want this result without removing the magicFields[] type

You have to “remove” it, or at least use satisfies instead of an annotation. If you write const x: X = {…} then you are throwing away any information about your initializer except for that it’s an X.  Why do you “want” the result without removing the annotation? What use case requires that?
